# Use of "possibly" vs. "possible"?

Tags: grammar

Why possibly and not possible? What is the adverb "possibly" modifying in this sentence?

> Setting a cut-off date, possibly sometime in the first half of 2018, would aim to protect plants vulnerable to dicamba.

Comment: Perhaps here "possibly" is used as a "sentence adverb", see https://www.lexico.com/en/grammar/sentence-adverbs

Comment: If you used 'possible', the sentence would imply that setting a date would only become possible in early 2018.

Comment: If you think about it, 'possibly' isn't geared to modify a verb per se. It is paraphrased by 'It is possible that' (eg in 'Possibly, I may be free next Tuesday') or 'which may be' (as in your example) or 'and the way I might succeed might be [by]' (eg in 'I might be able to get the lid off, possibly using a damp cloth'). etc etc.

Comment: //Setting a cut-off date, possibly sometime in the first half of 2018, would aim to protect plants vulnerable to dicamba.// It implies that the cut-off date being set possibly in the first half of..... and here, 'possibly' functions as an adverb.

Answer (score 1):

Per [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/possibly?s=t) *possibly* means "perhaps, maybe". So that phrase means "perhaps sometime in the first half of 2018".

In order to use *possible* you'd have to write something like:

> It's possible we would set the cutoff date sometime in the first half of 2018.